# ML learning curve: how to predict training set size to achieve certain classification accuracy?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, deep-learning, logarithm

I plotted a learning curve having number of training examples on X-axis and classification(binary) accuracy on Y-axis. Now I want to extrapolate the curve to find a measurement of training set needed to reach certain accuracy level. I heard the increment in accuracy with training set size is often logarithmic and I need to find the base of the logarithm. So, I want to plot a log(accuracy) vs log(no of training examples) and predict the required size of training set. But, I don't know how to find the base. Would frequently used log bases like 10 or e work or I need to calculate the base? If yes, how would I calculate the base?

Comment: This seems really similar to this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300856/amount-of-training-data-for-classification-accuracy/300891#3008911#300891

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2, e, or 10, it should be fine, and this isn't really exact science since you're assuming it's logarithmic without any basis anyway.

But... if you really want to be precise, then finding an unknown parameter that best fits the data is the whole idea behind machine learning! you can run any machine learning algorithm to predict the accuracy based on the N. The simplest, and maybe best here to avoid overfitting, is just to use linear regression to predict accuracy from log of N.

In general, you're trying to find base b to minimize the squared distance from the data you have, you can fins it with gradient descent. Or more simply in this case, just calculate the sum or squared distances for a bunch of dots, for a closed set of possible b - 2,e,3,4...10, and see which one is the best.. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

### Starting with *"I heard the ... is often ... "* could skew all your rigorous efforts

One, a rudimenetary grounded, **empirical-approach** would be to freely plot data in whatever scaling / transformation one wishes to, without any prejudice of what the mathematical approximation might be close to the set of the observed data -- your [ nExamples, nClassifier-mispredictions ] ( in days, when engineering does not need to work just with straight-rules on a polar, lin-lin, lin-log or log-log graph-paper, it is so, so free to opt for any kind of graph-output )

Second approach -- going more the theoretical way -- would be to plot the observed results against the graph of **Hoeffding-inequality**, which addresses the very theoretically formulated law of what you try to see in the graphed plot.