# Information content of a numerical dataset

Tags: machine-learning, experiment-design, information-theory

Please consider a dataset $n \times m$, composed exclusively of continuous values, and where $n \gg m$.

We wanted to use this dataset in a machine learning setting, as a training set.

To add instances to this dataset has an associated cost, hence, we are looking for the smallest possible set of instances.

I was wondering if there is a measure which tells us whether the benefits of adding another instance does not justify its cost. (i.e., something similar to an asymptotic saturation curve).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the algorithm that you want to use - in general the simpler the model, the less examples it needs to see to have decent accuracy.

One of concepts that measures this is Vapnik-Chervonenkis (VC) dimension. You can see for example my answer for [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/300856/amount-of-training-data-for-classification-accuracy/300891#300891).